# Windows 10 Default install directory

Tags: windows, windows-update

When trying to install any software on my computer, the sugested default installation directory is said by the software to be X:\programfiles. i have C:

This happend after some windows updates. i have windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by changing a key in regedit

1. Open regedt: 
   <kbd>Start</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd> and enter 'regedit' and run it.
2. **Locate the key:** HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE SOFTWAREMicrosoftMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersion
3. Finally locate the **string**
   *ProgramFileDir*. Change this to your desired location.

*Good Luck*

Comment: It says C:\Program Files.

Still the software wants to be installed on x:\Program Files

Comment: No. everything is suggested to be installed on x:\

Comment: @Wiccoll Do you have a drive x?

Comment: I do not have a drive x